# How do I install LHAPDF so I can use it in python on my macbook?

Tags: python, homebrew

I am trying to download LHAPDF for to use in my python code.

I am struggling on even finding out where to start.

Do I need to install a C++ compiler?

I have tried using Homebrew but get

jasper@Jaspers-MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % brew install lhapdf
Warning: No available formula with the name "lhapdf".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
Error: No formulae or casks found for lhapdf.

Is there any easy way of doing this?

Thanks in advance
Jasper

Comment: You have to download the source and build it yourself.  Yes, you need a C++ compiler, like Xtools.  The instructions are here, but they warn about troubles on MacOS.  https://lhapdf.hepforge.org/install.html

Comment: nixpkgs has lhapdf packaged.

Comment: ...indeed, `nix-shell -p '(python3.withPackages (p: [p.lhapdf]))'` works just fine (on a recent M1 Mac), downloading a precompiled build from [Hydra](https://github.com/NixOS/hydra) (cc: @TimRoberts); and Nix doesn't have Homebrew's gawdawful install-everything-in-a-user-writable-location security "design"; I don't use Homebrew, and don't recommend anyone else use it either.

Comment: @TimRoberts Thank you for your answer, could you give me a little bit more of a step by step, I am a physics student and whilst I know how to write code well enough for my purposes, I don't really understand how building it myself works.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I ran that and tried using lhapdf and get 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lhapdf'
Is there anything else I need to do before I can use it?
Thanks

Comment: @Jasperamirante, are you using the Python interpreter that Nix put in your path when you ran that code, or one you already had installed? It's only installed for the Nix-provided interpreter.

Comment: @Jasperamirante, ...when I run `nix-shell -p '(python3.withPackages (p: [p.lhapdf]))' --command python`, f/e, the interpreter that drops me into is one where `import lhapdf` works fine.